# ItemSource value can evaluate to decide the style between label or radio buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am looking for a wpf example of when Itemsource is more than 1 then it can creates radio button dynamically. If it just one value in Itemsource then it should be label instead of radio buttons. Do I have to write converter which can pass the value of Itemsource and control the style between label and radio button. If anyone can provide example then it will be great.

Comment: use contentpresenter with two datatemplates with different data types

Answer (score 1):

You may use a ItemContainerStyle with a DataTrigger on the `Count` property of the ItemsControl's `Items`.

The Style would chose between two different ContentTemplates, depending on whether there is exactly one item or not.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultItemTemplate">
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding ...}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleItemTemplate">
            <Label Content="{Binding ...}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource DefaultItemTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding Items.Count,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                    Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource SingleItemTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ContentControl` creates a control and chooses the correct `DataTemplate` for it based on its Type. So you don't need a converter:

```
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Child}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Type1}">
                <Label Content="{Binding ItemText}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Type2}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding ItemText}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
```

This code reacts to different types of `Child` property inside VM:

```
public BaseType Child { get; set; }
```

Data types:

```
public class BaseType { }
public class Type1 : BaseType
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
public class Type2 : BaseType
{
    public ObservableCollection<Type1> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Type1>();
}
```

for example if you set `Child` to a `Type1` it will show you one label

```
Child = new Type1 { ItemText = "hello" };
```

or if you set it to `Type2` you will have your radiobutton collection:

```
var t = new Type2();
t.Items.Add(new Type1 { ItemText = "hello" });
t.Items.Add(new Type1 { ItemText = "world" });
Child = t;
```